# Cant print iteration time inside the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I can't print iteration time inside a view I need - `i` var not growing:

```
- i=0; @movies[0..3].each do |movie|
  <input type="checkbox" name="ratings" value="#{i}">#{movie.rating}</input>
- i++;
```

What should be change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-@movies[0..3].each_with_index do |movie, i|
  %input{:type=>"checkbox" :name=>"ratings" :value=>i}
  %label
    =movie.rating
```